# Polymer classList.add() doesn't update class in DOM

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove a class to different spinner items. I'm setting the class of my spinner component like so in a method :

```
 _handleDelete(event) {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('spinner-component')[event.model.index].classList.add('spinner');
    //....lines of code...
}
```

Here is the template :

```
static get template() {
    return `
        <style>
            spinner-component {
                display: none;
            }
            .spinner {
                display: initial;
                z-index: 9;
            }

        </style>
        <spinner-component></spinner-component>
        <spinner-component></spinner-component>
        <spinner-component></spinner-component>
        ${super.template}
    `;
}
```

Then in debug, this is what I get after the classList.add line :

```
$0.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('iris-spinner')[0].classList
    DOMTokenList ["spinner", value: " spinner"]
        0: "spinner"
        length: 1
        value: " 
        spinner"__proto__: DOMTokenList
```

The problem is that the .spinner class is not applied to my spinner-component element. Moreover, it is still shown in the DOM as :

`<spinner-component></spinner-component>` instead of `<spinner-component class='spinner'></spinner-component>`

I found a workaround by using `this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('spinner-component')[event.model.index].className += ' spinner';` but I'd like to know why this happens.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (`handleDelete()` correctly adds/removes the class using `classList` in both Polymer 2 and 3). Can you provide a repro?